# How to attenuate the noise in the current due to the MOSFET switching

Tags: mosfet, noise, powermosfet

I am making a controller to like dimmer to reduce the voltage from a microcontroller. I am using the following circuit.

[image: Circuit diagram]

However, I see that this is introducing noise into the current. I need help to attenuate this noise. The noise in the current due to this MOSFET switching is given in the following scope.
[image: Noise in the current]

If I use a simple smoothing capacitor without any resistance, I get the following results.
[image: Circuit after adding smoothing capacitor]
[image: Noise in current is still observed after adding smoothing capacitor]

If I add a smoothing capacitor along with a resistance in series, I get the following results.

[image: Circuit after adding smoothing capacitor along with a resistance]
[image: Noise in current is still observed after adding smoothing capacitor along with a resistance]

Is there something I am missing? Also, if the tuning of the R and C values is required, what is the criteria?

Another update:
In the following, I present the circuit with higher value of capacitor value. The problem continues.

[image: Circuit using a high value for the smoothing capacitor]
[image: Noise in the current still exist with a high value for the smoothing capacitor]

In the following, I present the circuit with higher value of capacitor value. The problem continues.

[image: Circuit using a 1000uF smoothing capacitor]

[image: Noise in the current still exist with a high value for the smoothing capacitor]

Comment: What noise? It's exactly what you'd expect, a chopped up rectified sine wave. There's no smoothing capacitor.

Comment: @Unimportant , I updated my question. I included results with the smoothing capacitor. Is there a method to calculate the right value of RC values?

Comment: Try the first schematic (without the 100 ohm) but make the capacitor 1000µF in stead of 1. And measure the current at the MOSFET drain.

Comment: @Unimportant , I changed its value to 1000 uF and the plot seem to change but still there exist the current.

Comment: It's not noise. The blue graph is a nice clean square wave. Exactly what is expected when you're turning the MOSFET on and off at 1kHz. What did you expect?

Comment: @Unimportant,  I am expecting the red graph (current supplied by the AC mains) be a sine wave. I don't want the noise in my circuit enter the electric mains.

Comment: In the second and third scope traces you moved the current probe. As you expect, AC current is only drawn at peaks, to recharge the capacitor. If you want a sine current waveform, useful search term "Switching Power factor correction" aka PFC.

Comment: @user_1818839 , Thank you very much. I got the answer. The answer I am looking is exactly what you said. "Switching Power factor correction". But it seems difficult to implement. We need some intelligent part in the circuit. Also, I am seeing few passive circuits here https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=68570.

However, I am not sure what values to be used for the passive components. Help in that direction will be more complete to the solution.

Comment: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1077.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559563801007  ...   https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6561.pdf   ...   Hope can help you.

Comment: @Antonio51, Your reply is the answer I am expecting. You can write as answer, so that I will mark it as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is to "remove" the current ripple that occurs when chopping by a MOSFET.

In this case, PFC circuits are used which make the input current almost sinusoidal. Note that the output of the assembly is a stabilized DC voltage always higher than the peak voltage of the input generator. This voltage can then be used for various uses.

The choke itself can also be part of another circuit, which is the load.

It is obvious that the fact of "cutting" (multiplication) a wave (pseudo sinusoidal) by a "rectangular" function, will generate a significant "noise", which can be evaluated by a rapid FFT "calculation" during a simulation of the circuit.

Beyond a power of a "few" tens of Watt, in principle, it becomes "mandatory" to produce a circuit which will have to reduce this noise ("electrical" and "electromagnetic" in general) very significantly.

This is obviously necessary in a growing context of "electromagnetic interference's" (hence the EMC or other standards) created by "power" electronic circuits.

One of the solutions proposed is the use of a PFC (power factor correction) circuit. There are different possibilities of proceeding, the most widely used being a "chopping" making it possible to "make" the current consumed by the assembly "almost" sinusoidal and in "phase" with the voltage of the network.

Not "very" easy to implement, but don't be "afraid". To help understand the principles, here are examples of my "didactic" realizations. I hope these will be helpful.

Simulated with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm) ...

Simple mains power (one phase used) :

[What is the correct approach to simulate a predesigned circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/580479/what-is-the-correct-approach-to-simulate-a-predesigned-circuit/580504#580504)

Three phases mains power used :

[Need guidance in designing an LC low pass filter for 10 kW autotransformer-based power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/580944/need-guidance-in-designing-an-lc-low-pass-filter-for-10-kw-autotransformer-based/581092#581092)

These can be "digitized" for the "command" and "regulation" part.