# What is the correct approach to simulate a predesigned circuit?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, mosfet-driver, pspice, power-factor-correction

I want to simulate the following circuit with LTspice, but all the operating parts in the circuit (highlights) are not available in the library. I also couldn't find their spice models on the internet. Is there a problem with how I searched or are spice models on the internet so rare and difficult to find? After hours of surfing the internet, I found the IC model in a Chinese blog. Now I really don't know do I have the correct approach in this way?

Some friends recommended simulating the parts by myself, but I don't believe this is the optimum approach. Anyway, we are not living in 1980 and I'm not the first guy using these parts.

[image]

Comment: Welcome - what do you want to get out of your simulation? To use a simulation properly, you need to understand or have some intuition of how the circuit section will function. It is rarely a useful tool for a full circuit like this.

Comment: LTspice is offered by Linear to the public for free, but they use it internally for their own IC designs, which pays for its continued development. (The public pays nothing.) There was no way the folks writing the checks at Linear could be convinced to pay for the development and validation of models for competitors' ICs. So LTspice includes lots of Linear part models, but has a relatively significant *dearth* (lack) of competitor part models. The company just isn't going to help their competition. End of story. So this places you in a difficult place with STmicro parts.

Comment: As far as transformers go, you can wing that. Same with bridge rectifiers. Fuses are slightly tricky. But you can make that work without too much effort, too. The bottom line is to solve each problem, one at a time, and then move on. Most of your solutions will be useful the next time you encounter them. (For example, once you work out a "fuse model" that is satisfactory, you will have learned something that will be applicable over and over, later. So you don't have to solve it twice, just once.) ICs like the L6562A are in a different category. Either find something or write your own model.

Comment: This circuit is a "Transition-mode PFC controller". I used this far years ago. Search first for "how to do" PFC circuits (some methods). Need also some input mains filter. Will search if I found what I did with simulations.

Comment: "I want to simulate the following circuit by LTspice"  There's no reason to limit yourself to only LTspice. There are other, free, simulators out there that are just as reliable and may be able to support imported/custom models _easier_.  Since it's now free I'd suggest Microcap, though I personally find sim tools of limited use (low payoff/effort return) when it comes to attempting to sim a complete circuit.  Usually one is concerned about a specific section, or component(s), and that's all that needs to be sim'd.

Comment: @awjlogan , thanks, just want to ensure the operation of the system. you said "It is rarely a useful tool for a full circuit like this." Why is that so? I've heard frequently that, LTspice is one of the powerful tools. I'm also familiar with orcad capture. Which one do you suggest? However both are on SPICE basis.

Comment: @jonk thanks for your valuable advices. as this is my second language, what do you mean "As far as transformers go, you can wing that."?

Comment: @Kamran If you understand some relatively easy-to-gather details about simulating transformers in Spice (the coupling co-efficient uses the "K" card in Spice to achieve), then it's not too difficult. You can start with an ideal transformer made from two, appropriately valued inductors. You need to know how inductance scales with turns. (\$L\propto N^2\$) Then add a coupling coefficient. You will need to add some series resistance to each inductance, as appropriate. But you can much of this from datasheets or otherwise "wing it" by guessing.

Comment: @Kamran - so, you simulate it, and the circuit doesn't work, then what? Do you know where to start making changes? Are you models good? Simulation rarely gives _insight_ into how a circuit works, it is best used to solve analytic problems in particular blocks (exact values, what's causing ringing etc...). In this particular circuit, for example, look at `R4, 5` - simulation does not tell you why it's two identical resistors.

Comment: @awjlogan, well, thanks, surely I study the principles and understand the operation of each section; but besides the analytic aspect of simulation, I want to do this simulation for part selection. but according to your words, there is a gap between simulation and implementation. how can I be sure that the final simulated schematic is the exact diagram that I can implement part by part confidently? is there another EDA software for this purpose? or what should be my approach?

Comment: @Kamran - what parts do you need to select? This is straight from the datasheet, so will work; if you can't get a particular component, you can find an equivalent by comparing values. That might be a good use of simulation (if you can find models): eg, if you substitute `Q1` does it perform as well with the values of `R7/8` - you would just test that subcircuit, not the whole thing, and probably only a functional model of a gate driver, not of the the `L6562A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some links usefull https://www.electronicproducts.com/understanding-pfc/#

https://www.powerelectronicsnews.com/design-considerations-of-digital-controlled-totem-pole-pfc/

Very complete : pdf file ... https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiC1tuerp7yAhUJDuwKHV4UBvQQFnoECBsQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftoshiba.semicon-storage.com%2Finfo%2Fdocget.jsp%3Fdid%3D68570&usg=AOvVaw1SYCNsePCIMkU4dfTj-CZ1

This one for digital controlled PFC   https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Digital+PFC+CCM+Boost+Converter+-+300W+Design+Example+Using+XMC+1400-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462584d1d4a015886d4dcaa5ea4

For simulating this PFC, you can start by an "equivalent" schematic.

microcap v12 ... free ... from http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm

Vcrete is Vpeak ... Vredr is Vrectified ... Vch is Vload ... Vich is current in load ...

I hope symbolics are self-explaining ... I don't know if there is same "functions" in LTspice.

What is simulated here is a drop in main voltage.

What you can see is at the drop, current is higher for same output power.

The principle of the method is to "predict", as a reference, the shape of the sinusoidal curve of the "current in the choke" as a function of the power required in the load (voltage 24 V DC and current 1A DC fixed) and to try to follow it as well as possible (sometimes above, sometimes below) by making the power MOSFET lead in all-or-nothing by "small strokes" (hence the sawtooth shape of the current around.

The regulation is not the best, it is obviously a study set-up.

The current supplied by the source (~ 10V rms) is in principle "sinusoidal" with "triangles" and in a real system, it should therefore filtered by a EMI filter at the head of the assembly (voltage source side at 50 Hz, 240 Veff, EU).

As it is a low voltage assembly, you can "work" on it without too much "danger"!

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for your advice and sharing simulations. Yah, the results are nicely accurate. Is this simulator orcad capture? What's the name of pfc method applied?

Comment: Sorry. I forget. microcap v12 ... free ... from http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm

Comment: thanks my friend Antonio.

Comment: excuse me, as i searched just right now, microcap is also on SPICE  basis. What are its advantages compare to LTspice?

Comment: I used microcap since ... 40 years ... I don't remember :-) LTspice is usefull for the products now from Analog and Linear Technology ... I update my answer for some infos.