# How does a Vienna rectifier try to make its input current sinusoidal to reduce THD?

Tags: power-factor-correction

I cannot seem to figure out the working of the three phase Vienna rectifier for power factor correction. How do the various switching states cause the input current to be sinusoidal?

Comment: If you can understand how a conventional single-phase boost PFC regulator works and manages to have low THD then it gets easier for the Vienna rectifier. It basically consists of three conventional single-phase boost PFC regulators and they work out of phase. The timing is important, but there's no huge magic.

Comment: You should see this first https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/580479/what-is-the-correct-approach-to-simulate-a-predesigned-circuit/580504#580504

Comment: @RohatKılıç I looked into single phase boost converter based PFC circuits. I do understand the the working of the Vienna rectifier now. Hats off to you for pointing me in the right direction. There is one thing that confuses me a bit: Why should the voltage across the capacitors be maintained equal? I understand that a voltage imbalance causes the THD to increase, but I cannot figure out why?

Answer (score 1):

It is just a boost converter so it can be made to draw a current that is proportional to instantanious voltage, Sure you could do this with 3 boost converters  but the Vienna like its close relative the Warsaw              has a common DC bus  which means less bus capacitance. The Vienna  unlike the warsaw is a star based scheme so the peak device voltages are lower which can be an advantage. It can be shown that the vienna has lower switching losses than 3 single phase modules.