# Need guidance in designing an LC low pass filter for 10 kW autotransformer-based power supply

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, passive-filter

Autotransformer voltage tapping points are  220, 270, 320, 370, 420, 470, 520, 570, 620, 670 & 720 volts. The current rating is 16.5 A.

Power supply requirements are maximum 700 V output, minimum 200 V output, at constant 16.5 A current.

Can someone guide me in designing a second order inductor/capacitor low pass filter for the above power supply, especially L1, C1 values required?

Edit:
With L=120mH C=200uF or 220uF, I got the following results (attached)[image: Fig2]

Comment: Maybe this is not really what you want to do. Are you trying to filter out the mains ripple frequency of 100 Hz (or 120 Hz if you are in North America)? I think you will be hard pressed to have enough series impedance in an inductor to attenuate 120 Hz or below.

Comment: RL is the load, is it really something that you can choose?

Comment: The schematic you want using is called PD2 in power electronics. What are your specifications for current (Delta I max ) ? Load is "constant resistive" ... or something else ? For such current and power, it would be interesting using a PD3 ... because of the lower ripple.

Comment: What you've illustrated is an ***isolating*** transformer, not an ***autotransformer***. This is important if you are grounding the bridge rectifier output. It must be floating with an autotransformer, as you have a connection back to the mains input, and the neutral has a connection to ground.

Comment: Instead of L, for such low frequency and constant current application, a gyrator kind of circuit will be much easier.

Comment: Be carefull. GBPC3510 is very near , for voltage, to Vmax admissible 720*sqrt(2) = 1015 V. There is no margin for overvoltage ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is overvoltage (> 720 Vac, no Safety) in this case, another bridge should be needed.

With an inductor at the head, we cannot obtain the desired voltage of 700V DC (655 max, figure 1).

And if the value of the choke decreases, we go back to rectifier on capacity (figure 2), and there will be very high current peaks.

EDIT 2 : It should be interesting exploring another way.

Here a schematic which is a PFC circuitry. Good point of starting. Made with a number of MOSFETs (15) which can be replaced with 1 modern SiC device.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT :**
**SAFETY ...
APPLY all Safety Rules which are ESSENTIAL when working with such voltages and currents. I don't assume anything. This is only for EDUCATION.**

A **complete operational "device"** must measure or calculate all values of currents, voltages, powers, temperatures ... **in Real Time** and **switch off immediately all, if not ok... except fans :-) .**

**For testing such "devices" or "boards" ... begin ALWAYS with lowest voltages, if possible .**
**Be very care full choosing all components (diodes, L, C1) with peak (if any) and RMS values ...**

**Do simulation also when switching on power.**

**End point : try to always switch ON power systems at 0 V, with "smart switches" (triacs or others systems).**
Something as this : https://docs.rs-online.com/5e02/A700000007106456.pdf, (**point 3, page 3 : Full conduction mode voltage, some have input for 220 V directly). *One can adjust on device the "initial phase angle controller" with potentiometer.** *Don't use "phase control" with transformer without simulation.**

[image: case of Inductor]

[image: case of Capacitor]

[image: Mix of the 2]

Example of results simulation. Swith ON at Vsin = Vmax (phase = 90 degree)

[image]

[image]

Comment: With bridge rectifier of rating 1.5kV/2kV, L1=100mH, C1=200uF we get max dc output voltage of 698V. The cutoff frequency value is 35.59 Hz in this case.
Will it work...? 
For AC to DC filtering, what value of cut off frequency is selected, generally. we have 220V 50Hz input.

Comment: I think yes. But pay close attention. You need to calculate these components (L and C) from the point of view of the voltage, current and "power" flowing through them. I will make a complete calculation. Coming soon.

Comment: Power supply is mean to be used in our service center for Solar Inverters testing. As inverters usually have input dc voltage ratings in the range of 100-700V.
ripple factor needs to be under 10%.

Comment: Current is always 16 A in "charge RL" ?

Comment: 16-17A , can't exceed 20A as there is 20A fuse.

Comment: @ihsan.duet11   -  I edit answer with a circuit which is a mix between the 2 presented. Added L2 -C2 -and resistor to limit peak of currents. Analysis may be done with microcap12, TRAN analysis. Select a component and use arrow keys (up or down) for changing values easily.

Comment: from this one we can get our desired 700v dc but there is high current peaks problem.
Let our desired output voltage is 655 or 650v dc instead of 700. then what about the first model you have presented above....as there is no high current peaks problem....

Comment: @ihsan.duet11  See edit for warnings

Comment: Edit: with L=120mH and C=220/200uF, I got the above results in attached img. no high peak currents or voltage issues. Will it work...?

Comment: If you have switch at V=0 in simulation, it is logical (no peaks). For my simulation, I switched at V = Vmax to see really max peak currents for "taking care" components in all cases.

Comment: Switch on at V=0 and as for as components ratings is concerned, I have used a 20A fuse before bridge rectifier and also thinking of using 20A-25A MCB circuit breaker before the circuit, for extra protection purpose as we can't trust auto transformer.

Comment: Will it work safely or an extra effort is needed on above circuit.....

Comment: For critical/minimum inductance for LC filter, I found the attached material below,,,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x6Q6.png
In our case, RL= 40-50 ohms, it gives critical inductance values in the range of 260mH to 293mH. While I have chosen L1=120mH for my design.
Will that be an issue as in our case L1=120mH well below critical inductance value.
Also I have read somewhere that for better filtering the inductance value should be greater than critical inductance.

Comment: If L is too low, of course, you will work as a "head capacitor", thus with peak of currents at start and also later.

Comment: I doubt about the fact that "ripple is independent of RL", or current flowing in it.

Comment: Have a look to this   [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t59Zt.png    to see why there is a "critical inductance" (current = 0 a "long" time). Take a look also to voltage over inductance. Don't forget simulation secondary inductance also. Don't forget that "internal impedance" in such power supply is proportional to IL and L, and may be high.

Comment: Does the ripple current matter while selecting a capacitor...?
Current in my case is 16.5A (Power supply) while most of the capacitors (Aluminium Electrolytic cap) I have searched have ripple currents from mA to 1.7A.

Comment: @ihsan.duet11 In my simulation, current through capacitor has almost 20 A peak (+ and -). So it is important to have almost min 1000V and 20 A rms ... example as this https://docs.rs-online.com/7b06/0900766b814105f7.pdf ( 2 in serial possibly with resistors for balancing ??? ).  Also some as these ... https://docs.rs-online.com/53c4/0900766b81524c52.pdf 1200 V or 1500V  but only 22 uF or 15 uF. so you need paralleling some. Current rms for each ... 50 A ... Don't forget a fuse for each one. And a safe "cage" ... :-)

Comment: what about the caps (68uF, Vac 780v & vdc 1700v) on page 4 of the attached document.
https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/212/1/KEM_F3117_C44P_R-1761431.pdf
As I have chosen C=68uF & L=220mH.
But the main problem is L (220mH) with required current ratings, as all the inductors with 25-40A current ratings are in uH range or few mH (1 to 10mH) range. how can I find L=220mH with 30-40A current ratings.

Comment: This kind of inductor may be self done. Must evaluate the reactive part of current, voltage and "reactive power". Then take an auto-transformer of this "power", with some tapping points near full charge (be carefull, use "full" primary, it is an overvoltage transformer !) and evaluate the inductance at full charge. One may hope that one tapping point is "good". Otherwise, it will be necessary to apply the good old methods of electricians to size an inductor of this type. Take into account that DC current will saturate the core. It will "undoubtedly" be necessary to provide an air gap.

Comment: Another way (with current chopping) should be "simpler", in any case for the realization of the inductance which should then work at higher frequency.

Comment: @ihsan.duet11  See my Edit 2 for such power (12 kW - 15 kVAr), a design for mains 3N400 - 3x 220V. may be change if needed.