# Current specifications of the boost inductor

Tags: inductor, boost, power-factor-correction

The following calculations refer to the boost inductor of a PFC boost pre-regulator. ILac is defined as the ac inductor current.as it says "ac inductor current" and its value is calculated as 0.59 made me confused. the attached figure contains IL, ILpeak, and ILave, and the corresponding values are also calculated below. now, what is the "ac inductor current" which its value is 0.59? what is its concept? [the corresponding application note](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00195944-solution-for-designing-a-transition-mode-pfc-preregulator-with-the-l6562a-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this homework? What have you found out so far?

Comment: @winny, no it's for designing an 80W PFC by L6562 according to its application note. can you clarify the confusions?

Comment: *for designing an 80W PFC by L6562* Include that in the question, not as a comment. Also include a link to the datasheet and/or wherever you found the drawing and the formulas. *How is the waveform?* Uh, it is plotted in the figure you show? *What is the definition?* Uh, also defined in your formulas? You're asking your question in a confusing way. To me, you ask a question and then the answer is also there!?!?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, thanks for your explanations. my question is in general. as it says "ac inductor current" and its value is calculated as 0.59 made me confused. the attached figure contains  IL, ILpeak, and ILave, and the corresponding values are also calculated as above. now, what is the "ac inductor current" which its value is 0.59? what is its concept? [the corresponding application note](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00195944-solution-for-designing-a-transition-mode-pfc-preregulator-with-the-l6562a-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Comment: The "ac inductor current" is the rms value of inductor current ... but "around" "average inductor current", so your formula says ILac, I think not really usefull. Most usefull are Ipeak max (for demagnetization) and ILrms.

Comment: @Antonio51 thanks sir Antonio, post it as the final answer so I will accept it.

Comment: You need to determine the rms current in one high-frequency cycle then integrate over half the mains period to obtain the rms current in the inductor. This is described in an old ON Semi application note [PFC Stages operated in CrM](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8123-D.PDF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ac inductor current" is the rms value of inductor current ... but "around" "average inductor current", so your formula says ILac (for knowing mains current input), I think not really usefull for inductor. Most usefull are Ipeak max (for demagnetization concerns) and ILrms.

For added information, this "kind of current" is not the "best" to use because if the peak is 'sinusoidal", the harmonic contents is greater then another form of current which really models a "sinusoid".

TOSHIBA Power Factor Correction (PFC) Circuits Application Note [pdf file reference](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiC1tuerp7yAhUJDuwKHV4UBvQQFnoECBsQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftoshiba.semicon-storage.com%2Finfo%2Fdocget.jsp%3Fdid%3D68570&usg=AOvVaw1SYCNsePCIMkU4dfTj-CZ1)

For education :

See this post : [Need guidance in designing an LC low pass filter for 10 kW autotransformer-based power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/580944/need-guidance-in-designing-an-lc-low-pass-filter-for-10-kw-autotransformer-based/581092#581092)

and this one : [What is the correct approach to simulate a predesigned circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/580479/what-is-the-correct-approach-to-simulate-a-predesigned-circuit/580504#580504)